# clarification about Algorithm of page replacement LRU with reference bits

Tags: operating-systems, paging, virtual-memory

Studying LRU approximation Algorithms I think to have not understand how it works, for example:

```
consider a process with 3 logical pages and 2 frames allocated , an approximation of the
Algorithm Last Recently Used based of reference bits where every four references there is
a shift and where are considered just the first 2 bits, and the follow reference string:
```

> 1 2 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0

I'd solve it in this way:

> 1 2 1 1 **(*m1)*** 1 1 **(*m2)*** 0 1 0 0

**(*m1)***

4 references so I'd pass from

```
 frame                     frame
 -----+---+---     to       -----+---+---
    1 | 1 | 0                  1 | 0 | 1 
    2 | 1 | 0                  2 | 0 | 1
```

**(*m2)***

page fault so I'd pass from

```
 frame                     frame
 -----+---+---     to       -----+---+---
    1 | 1 | 1                  1 | 0 | 0 
    2 | 0 | 1                  0 | 0 | 0
```

So the questions are:

- Is my doing correct?
- At **m2** there is a page fault, is there a "reset" and all bits puts at 0?
- the shift frequency (4 in the example) restart counting every page fault?

Answer (score 2):

> Is my doing correct?

If I don't misunderstand your notation, when you manipulate the frame for first time (filling it with page 1, then page 2) and then page 1 is called again, you shouldn't send to disk page 2, there is no need because page 1 it is already in frame.